# move multiple image from uri to folder

Tags: android

i am trying to move multiple selected images from gallery to the storage folder, i have already picked multiple image from gallery in **ArrayList mArraylist** but i have no idea to save the selected images to the folder, plz help me, below is the code that i have picked images from gallery.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
int PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE = 1;
String imageEncoded;
List<String> imagesEncodedList;

ImageView img_view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    img_view = findViewById(R.id.img_view);

    img_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"),PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
        }
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            imagesEncodedList = new ArrayList<String>();
            if(data.getData()!=null){

                Uri mImageUri=data.getData();
                
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

            } else {
                if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                    ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                    ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                        ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                        Uri uri = item.getUri();
                        mArrayUri.add(uri);
                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        imagesEncodedList.add(imageEncoded);
                        cursor.close();

                    }
                    Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images" + mArrayUri.size());
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

Comment: You can remove all your code. Then tell that you picked an image and have obtained an uri like Uri uri = data.getData();. Then ask how to make a copy of that file. You dont have to talk about multiple files as everybody will believe that if you can copy one file you can copy more.

Comment: Do you know how to add one image to Storage folder?

Comment: Yes of course. Copying a file is a pretty standard action. And code for that has been published so often.